# How to assign a change in value of a variable from child controller to parent controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In this code, we have a parent controller and a child controller. In the HTML, notice that the parent controller encloses the child controller. In the parent controller, I am using a $controller service, which gets the child controller's scope. child controller's $scope.Child will be assigned to $scope.Parent. There is a button when clicked, would change the $scope.Child to "new child" value in child controller.

I am trying to achieve the same change in the parent controller as well. I was **expecting** the $scope.Parent to get the value as "new child" as well by putting a $watch() on $scope.Child. But the change in the value of child controller's $scope.Child is not being reflected in $scope.Parent

So, my **question** is how do I assign the change in the value of $scope.Child in the child controller to the parent controller?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.controller('parent', function($scope,$controller){  
        var childScope = $controller('child',{$scope: $scope});
        $scope.Parent = $scope.Child; 
        $scope.$watch('Child',function(){
            $scope.Parent = $scope.Child;
        },true);
    });

    app.controller('child',function($scope){
        $scope.Child = "child";
        $scope.changeValue = function() {
            $scope.Child = "new child";
        }
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="parent">
    <p>this is parent: {{Parent}}</p>
    <div ng-controller="child">
        <p>this is {{Child}}</p>
        <button ng-click="changeValue()">Click!</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) - dispatches the event **upwards** through the scope hierarchy, a.e. in basic words - notify parent controller from child controller.

```
$scope.changeValue = function() {
        $scope.Child = "new child";
        $scope.$emit('onChildChange', {data: $scope.Child});
    }
```

In parent controller:

```
$scope.$on('onChildChange', function (event, result) {
    console.log(result.data)
});
```

Some [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/714/) how it works

---

about your example:

```
 var childScope = $controller('child',{$scope: $scope});
 $scope.Parent = $scope.Child; 
 $scope.$watch('Child',function(){
    $scope.Parent = $scope.Child;
 },true);
```

Its not good practice to load child scope in parent controller. It can cause to unexpected behavior and its really hard to handle this kind of code.
Further, *deep* watch a.e. `$scope.$watch({}, true)` is a overkill that will effect on performance. In our case `$emit` will fire event and who listens on this event will catch it. No redundant watchers here